# Web service client application on weblogic to invoke web service

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, weblogic

I have a web application on weblogic 10.3.3 which is the client for invoking a secure web service.
Note: I have been able to test the web service through a stand-alone java class by setting 
the two properties below:

```
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/keystore.jks");
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "######");
```

But when i try to deploy the client application to weblogic, it gives me the below error:

```
weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.soapfault.WLSOAPFaultException: Failed to receive m
essage javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: [Security:090477]Certificate chain receive
d from *******  was not trusted causing SSL handshake failure.
        at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.fireException(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.fireAlertSent(Unknow
n Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.fireAlert(Unknown
Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.fireAlert(Unknown
Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.ClientStateReceivedServerHello.hand
le(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.handleHandshakeMes
sage(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.handshake.HandshakeHandler.handleHandshakeMes
sages(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.interpretContent(Unknown S
ource)
```

In weblogic console i have checked the "SSL Listen Port Enabled" checkbox.
In Keystores tab I have selected "Custom identity and Standard Trust Store". And for custom identity I have pointed to C:/keystore.jks.

Answer (score 1):

The *keystore* is where you put *your* keys. You will use these to prove who you are to your peer. This is most likely what is meant by "Custom Identity". The *truststore* is where you put your trust anchors. These are the certificates that you already trust, and your peer must present you a certificate chain that ends with one of the certificates in the trust store. As a degenerate case, you can put the peer certificate itself right into this truststore. This degenerate case must be used for self-signed certificates.

For most normal SSL uses the truststore includes well know CA roots like Verisign, Thawte, GoDaddy, Comodo, GlobalSign, etc. The Oracle JRE include a truststore in a file usually named `cacerts` that contains a large collection of such CA roots that Oracle thinks should be there. This is most likely what is meant by "Standard Trust Store".

I'm guessing your peer is using a self-signed certificate. Therefore you should use a custom truststore containing this certificate.